# Search modifiers in AWS AppSync and GrahphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to develop a GraphQL API with AWS AppSync + Amplify. My model looks like -

```
type AudioMetadata @model @searchable {
    id: ID!,
    title: String!,
    description: String!,
    category: [String]!,
    duration: Int!
}
```

As you can tell, this is backed by DynamoDB and Amazon Elastic Search. I want to have a `Query` that takes in search modifiers for searching. Search Modifiers are Slack-like modifiers and take the form `id:`, `intitle:`, `indescription:`, `duration_lt:`, and `duration_gt:`.

When searching, I'd like to search from ElasticSearch.

My question is how can I write a `Query` that caters to these search modifiers (maybe take in the search modifier and a search string) and searches against that field in Elastic Search.

Comment: Here is an example: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#add-a-custom-geolocation-search-resolver-that-targets-an-elasticsearch-domain-created-by-searchable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user Yik San Chan mentioned in the comments, a great example would be https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#add-a-custom-geolocation-search-resolver-that-targets-an-elasticsearch-domain-created-by-searchable

In your case you would have to create additional graphql queries in the schema to handle the various values you want to search by (i.e. intitle, indescription) and create the resolvers for each of these queries. Follow the examples on the link above.